# Maximum on the sphere vs. value at the center

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

Given $k$ arbitrary points $P_1, P_2, ..., P_k$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the function $f(P)=|PP_1|.|PP_2|...|PP_k|$, where $P \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that the maximum of $f$ on the unit sphere is larger than 1?

For the circle, we can think of $f(P)$ as the modulus of a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, and the conclusion follows easily. However, this argument cannot be applied to higher dimensions.

---

For more details ($n=2$), let $z_{i}$ be arbitrary points with $|z_{i}|=1$. Consider $p(z)=(z-z_{1})\cdots (z-z_{k})$. We have $|p(0)|=|z_{1}\cdots z_{k}|=1$, so by maximum modulus principle, we get $\max _{|z|=1} |p(z)|\geq |p(0)|=1$.

Comment: @arctictern $P_{i}$'s are arbitrarily chosen.

Comment: Ah. The question is if the maximum is bigger than $1$ no matter what the $P_1,\cdots,P_k$ are. I wasted a whole lot of comments, sorry everyone.

Comment: @Pluviophile Can you post your proof here? I want to see it.

Comment: @Pluviophile Posting an answer to your own question is allowed and even encouraged, especially given that others are interested in seeing the proof.